# How to use a abstract method in a class in my android activity?

Tags: java, android, class, android-activity, abstract

I am always bad in java. Could please give me any idea about the following situation?

I have a standalone java class which has an abstract method. Code as follows

```
public class MyLocation{

public boolean getLocation(Context context, LocationResult result)
{
-----------------------------------
Some code here
-----------------------------------
}

public static abstract class LocationResult{
        public abstract void gotLocation(Location location);
    }
}
```

Now I have to use the above class in my activity to get the location. I am not sure how to use this to get the current location by using the above class. Please help me. It will be better if you can provide some example code. I am not able to understand the abstract things in java.

Comment: `getLocation(..)` is not called by you, but by some external code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to extend the LocationResult class like this:

```
MyClass extends `LocationResult`
```

And then implement the abstract method:

```
 public abstract void gotLocation(Location location)
{
   //Do something with your result
   Location locationResult = location;
}
```

Or alternatively create an anonymous inner class, but since you are new to Java the above method is easier.

Comment: thanks for the code. But still I need more help, like as Location result is a member public class defined inside MyLocation class, do I need to create an instance of my location class? If I need to where should I instantiate the MyLocation class in my activity?